# Setting browser home page administratively

Tags: homepage

We have a requirement to use a single browser homepage across our whole organisation.  This isn't a problem for our IE users, thanks to group policy, but we have several Firefox/Opera/Chrome users, and as far as I can tell, there isn't a way of administratively setting the homepages on those browsers, either through the registry or by adding/manipulating files on the user's PC.

Does anyone know any different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox I know has a group policy template you can get called [FirefoxADM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firefoxadm/), not sure how up-to-date it is but there's an ADM to ADMX migrator around there somewhere if needed ^^

Obviously, if the end-users are free to install and/or run whatever application they want, this cannot be 100% enforced, eg. FirefoxADM won't work with portable installations and so on.

- Google Chrome - haven't really found anything but building on their [Google Update templates](http://www.google.com/support/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146164) might be a start.

Comment: That should take care of most of them.  All our Chrome/ium users also use Firefox, and I'm the only Opera user.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I'd encourage anyone to figure out or write the scripts or even the templates needed for the other browsers, this is something I've been pondering over before but sadly never got around to :7